# Spring Boot - external property not found

Tags: spring, web, spring-boot

My application is trying to externalize all project properties, some ones will be inside my app and another ones will be in a folder somewhere in Windows.

I set up Spring to execute this way: --spring.config.location=file:///C:\Temp\config\application.properties,classpath:application.properties

As you can see, if the same property exists in both sides, application property will be kept (priority order). I noticed for example some properties such as "server.port" can be found if exists outside folder (file://) but if I create one such "common.acronym-name" my project can not find its value.

Why "server.port" has a different behaviour that one create by me? Is there any configuration I need to tell Spring Boot to see this external property in my project?

```
@Value("${common.acronym-name:}") //Just find it in application classpath
private String acronymEnv;
```

Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce this, all seems as expected. values from classpath properties file override external file properties, if no value exists to override, the external value is used. Same behaviour for `common.acronym-name` as for `server,port`. There must be something in your setup you're not showing that is responsible for what you're seeing. Maybe create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I noticed the order of properties is making difference for the external file, is there any requirement for Spring Boot? I noticed if I have only a application.prop in my classpath the order does not affect.

Comment: No, I cannot reproduce that either.

Comment: Please try to create a class to get "spring.main.show-banner" property value, as the example I posted below.

Comment: I noticed that Spring Boot can not read external property rightly, if I try to read only the external property the banner still shows when is at top. java -jar sample-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar -Dspring.config.location=file:///C:\Temp\config\application.properties

Answer (score 0):

Believe or not, the order of properties makes difference for external properties be found.

If I set this below order where "spring.main.show_banner" is the first one at the top, my properties can not be found. For example:

spring.main.show-banner=false
server.port=9043
server.session-timeout=1800
server.ssl.key-store=file:///C:/Temp/config/localhost.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=localhost
server.ssl.key-password=localhost

So, If change to below order, everything works fine:

server.port=9043
server.session-timeout=1800
server.ssl.key-store=file:///C:/Temp/config/localhost.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=localhost
server.ssl.key-password=localhost
spring.main.show-banner=false

Is there any reason for it? Spring Boot needs to have the properties in right order? Seems the "server" section must the first one in the properties.

thanks.

Comment: No, I cannot reproduce that at all. All works fine here, in either order specified here. Can you please create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows this behaviour and post the whole thing here. Something in your setup that you're not posting is causing this, it's not normal. While doing so, you may even discover yourself what that is.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate this error, just create a class to handle the banner, for example:

```
@Component
public class ShowBanner {

    @Value("${spring.main.show-banner:}")
    private String showBanner;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println(showBanner);
    }
}
```

In this code if you set at external property file the property "spring.main.show-banner=false" the banner still shows in console if it is set before server section. When the banner should not appear. Because the property returns empty.

If I move the property after server section the banner disappears, because return false value as expected.

Keep in mind my application.properties project is empty.

By the way, Even running via Eclipse or java console it happens:
java -jar sample-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar --spring.config.location=file:///C:\Temp\config\application.properties,application.properties

Why?

Comment: I've also tried this. The banner doesn't show, the `println()` prints `false`, regardless of whether I put the property on the first line, or the last line of the external properties file. Something weird is going on here.

Comment: I agree.. and another properties have this same behaviour, I just told you about show-banner to demonstrate whats going on...